# How to support all screen size's in android compose?

Tags: android, screen-size

I made a dictionary app using compose in kotlin and I finished it a few days ago but I dont know how to support all screen sizes in compose. Actually I searched in the internet how can I support all screen sizes in compose but I couldn't figure out exactly how to apply it to my codes. I have many screens and when I searched on the internet, they did things like `if` `else` for each screen, as far as I understand, if it's this size, it's like this, if it's that size, it's like this. It just seemed silly to me, frankly, I wrote a lot of code and couldn't figure out how to re-arrange them this way. Isn't there an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

To support all screen sizes first you need to detect the current(Mobile, tablet, foldable ...) screen size in Material3
there is a window-size class that can help you.
Add these dependencies

```
 //Material 3
implementation "androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.1"
implementation "androidx.compose.material3:material3-window-size-class:1.0.1"
```

And for more info check out [Support different screen sizes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/large-screens/support-different-screen-sizes)